# Looping through n buttons in a layout

Tags: java, android

Is there a way to loop through set of buttons in some layout with id.
I have tableRow with n-number of buttons and I need to loop through them.

End functionality would be having row of buttons with max one being pressed (when another one is pressed it would do setPressed(false))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess, you can do something like this

```
ViewGroup layout = findViewById(R.id.your_layout);
for (int i = 0; i < layout.getChildCount(); i++) {
    View child = layout.getChildAt(i);
    if (child instanceof Button) {
        // Operate with button
    }
}
```